# UIscrollview resize problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uiscrollview

i have a srollview with textfields and labels as its subview, for two textfields i want to show UIpickerview.
For example: when user touches textfield11 i want to show a picker that slides up from the bottom of the screen, at this point i want to change height of my scrollview too, but it is not working.

```
CGRect scrollframe = scrollView.frame;
    NSLog(@"scrollframe.height=%f, pick height=%f",scrollframe.size.height, pick.frame.size.height);
    scrollframe.size.height -= pick.frame.size.height;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"start" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [scrollView setFrame:scrollframe];
    NSLog(@"scroll height = %f",scrollframe.size.height);
    NSLog(@"scrollview height = %f", scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [pick setFrame:CGRectOffset([pick frame], 0, -220)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

This is console log..

2011-06-08 10:43:31.316 AESDirect[281:207] scrollframe.height=416.000000, pick height=216.000000
2011-06-08 10:43:31.316 AESDirect[281:207] scroll height = 200.000000
2011-06-08 10:43:31.317 AESDirect[281:207] scrollview height = 200.000000
[image: before scrolling]

[image: after scrolling]

Comment: Why do you want to increase the height of the scrollview? If what you want is to move the other fields up you can change the contentoffset of the scrollview

Comment: i am not trying to increase its height , i am trying to decrease its height, like we do when we want to prevent keyboard from hiding textfields

Comment: for that only you can change the contentOffset rather than height. Set the contentoffset for the scrollview and the fields will go up accordingly

Comment: @problemChild Hi, is the picker moving up while animating?

Comment: @sripriya  yes picker is moving while animating.

Comment: @7KV7 i think contentoffset is used to determine visible area. am i right??

Comment: you can set it to show the textfields when keyboard appears

Comment: ok now suppose i am changing contentoffset to show textfields, now if i scroll my scrollview it will scroll picker too(check screenshot2) and that is the main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

```
[scrollframe setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollframe.contentOffset.x, scrollframe.contentOffset.y-100)];
```

You can call the above code via the same function from where you are calling the pickerView. So this way you don't have to change the height of the scrollview.

Your code should be like this then:

```
       UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
self.view = contentView;

UIScrollView *horizontalScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[horizontalScroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[horizontalScroll setDelegate:self];
[contentView addSubview:horizontalScroll];

UIPickerView *tempPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 220, 320, 100)];
[tempPicker setHidden:YES];
[contentView addSubview:tempPicker];
```

Make all three of them as Global in .h file and then you will have better control on their behavior. Your picker view is moving along with other items of scroll view because you might have add picker view as subview on  your scroll view.

Comment: problem is still there. btw scrollview contentsize is (320,665), when i am tapping on origin state textfield, picker is sliding up(screenshot 1), but scrollview's height is not decreasing. so if picker is visible and i am scrolling picker is moving too in the direction of scroll like all other subviews are moving

Comment: Comment this line: [pick setFrame:CGRectOffset([pick frame], 0, -220)]; in your code
 and hide picker view initially while creating and only change it's visibility to Yes, when required. Don't change it's offset.

Comment: thank you friends for your response, my problem is solved thanks to Prabh and gypsa.
Actually i was adding it as scrollview's subview.
scrollview was created by client in IB and he had loaded UIscrollview to main window and i thought he was using UIView.
Sorry for wasting your time.
thanx 7KV&, SriPriya, Prabh and gypsa for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your contentsize and content offset and pickerview in view not in scroll view because if you add it in scroll view you will not be able to select values from picker view.